# XML XPath not working

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have the following 2 lines of code:

```
Dim node As XmlNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//response/agentStatusList/agentStatus/protectableVolumes/protectableVolume/metrics/lastWriteTime")
MsgBox(node.FirstChild.Value)
```

I'm looking to get the value for first instance of `lastWriteTime` which should be `2011-10-13T10:48:48.3833771-04:00` but the code just pops up an empty string. Sorry for the big post but here is the entire XML file for reference. Can anyone see why this isn't working, or give me an example of how to make it work some other way?

```
<responses xmlns="replayc.Xml.Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <response>
    <commandName>GetAgentStatus</commandName>
    <errorMessage i:nil="true"/>
    <message>The GetSourceStatus is executed successfully.</message>
    <responseCode>0</responseCode>
    <stackTrace i:nil="true"/>
    <time>2011-10-13T10:48:48.3364607-04:00</time>
    <agentStatusList>
      <agentStatus>
        <allowAccessDuringRollbackFlag>true</allowAccessDuringRollbackFlag>
        <areDriversLoaded>true</areDriversLoaded>
        <backupWindowDuration>0</backupWindowDuration>
        <backupWindowStartTime>0001-01-01T00:00:00</backupWindowStartTime>
        <checksumCheckInProgress>false</checksumCheckInProgress>
        <checksumCheckJobSchedule>
          <recurrence>Nightly</recurrence>
          <weeklyDayOfWeek>Sunday</weeklyDayOfWeek>
        </checksumCheckJobSchedule>
        <clusterName/>
        <continuousSourceRollbackInfo>
          <enabled>false</enabled>
          <finishTime>0001-01-01T00:00:00</finishTime>
          <hotStandbyName/>
          <hotStandbyTargetIp/>
          <inProgress>false</inProgress>
          <lastReplicationTime>0001-01-01T00:00:00</lastReplicationTime>
          <percentDone>0</percentDone>
          <recoveryPointTimeStamp>0001-01-01T00:00:00</recoveryPointTimeStamp>
          <rollbackVolumeInfoMapDict/>
          <startTime>0001-01-01T00:00:00</startTime>
        </continuousSourceRollbackInfo>
        <currentRpExportStatus>
          <exportInProgress>false</exportInProgress>
          <exportStatusString>Off</exportStatusString>
          <finishTime>0001-01-01T00:00:00</finishTime>
          <isDifferentialExport>false</isDifferentialExport>
          <percentDone>0</percentDone>
          <recoveryPointTimeStamp>0001-01-01T00:00:00</recoveryPointTimeStamp>
          <startTime>0001-01-01T00:00:00</startTime>
        </currentRpExportStatus>
        <currentVmExportStatus>
          <exportInProgress>false</exportInProgress>
          <exportStatusString>Off</exportStatusString>
          <finishTime>0001-01-01T00:00:00</finishTime>
          <isDifferentialExport>false</isDifferentialExport>
          <percentDone>0</percentDone>
          <recoveryPointTimeStamp>0001-01-01T00:00:00</recoveryPointTimeStamp>
          <startTime>0001-01-01T00:00:00</startTime>
        </currentVmExportStatus>
        <edbsAndStatuses/>
        <enableLogTruncation>false</enableLogTruncation>
        <errorMsg/>
        <exchangeVersion>None</exchangeVersion>
        <forceDismountFlag>false</forceDismountFlag>
        <forceLogTruncation>false</forceLogTruncation>
        <haFeatures>ExchangeHaFeatureNone</haFeatures>
        <ipAddress>10.28.95.81</ipAddress>
        <logPath>e:\tevorepository\appassure</logPath>
        <name>appassure</name>
        <newestLastChanged>2011-10-13T10:48:48.2739055-04:00</newestLastChanged>
        <policyFlagsEdb>0</policyFlagsEdb>
        <policyFlagsSql>0</policyFlagsSql>
        <port>8004</port>
        <protectableVolumes>
          <protectableVolume>
            <isExchangeInstallVolume>false</isExchangeInstallVolume>
            <isSqlInstallVolume>false</isSqlInstallVolume>
            <metrics>
              <bytesTransfered>0</bytesTransfered>
              <lastWriteTime>2011-10-13T10:48:48.3833771-04:00</lastWriteTime>
              <totalBytesToTransfer>0</totalBytesToTransfer>
              <transferFinishTime>2011-10-13T10:48:48.3833771-04:00</transferFinishTime>
              <transferStartTime>2011-10-13T10:48:48.3833771-04:00</transferStartTime>
              <volumeName/>
            </metrics>
            <name i:nil="true"/>
            <sqlInstances/>
            <storageGroups/>
            <tevoDriverGuid>301fbed8-de11-11e0-8b0f-76c786fecbc5</tevoDriverGuid>
            <tevoDriverGuidStr>301fbed8-de11-11e0-8b0f-76c786fecbc5</tevoDriverGuidStr>
            <uniqueId>C:</uniqueId>
            <validForProtection>true</validForProtection>
          </protectableVolume>
          <protectableVolume>
            <isExchangeInstallVolume>false</isExchangeInstallVolume>
            <isSqlInstallVolume>false</isSqlInstallVolume>
            <metrics>
              <bytesTransfered>0</bytesTransfered>
              <lastWriteTime>2011-10-13T10:48:48.3833771-04:00</lastWriteTime>
              <totalBytesToTransfer>0</totalBytesToTransfer>
              <transferFinishTime>2011-10-13T10:48:48.3833771-04:00</transferFinishTime>
              <transferStartTime>2011-10-13T10:48:48.3833771-04:00</transferStartTime>
              <volumeName/>
            </metrics>
            <name i:nil="true"/>
            <sqlInstances/>
            <storageGroups/>
            <tevoDriverGuid>301fbed7-de11-11e0-8b0f-76c786fecbc5</tevoDriverGuid>
            <tevoDriverGuidStr>301fbed7-de11-11e0-8b0f-76c786fecbc5</tevoDriverGuidStr>
            <uniqueId>C:\Windows\SRPPartition</uniqueId>
            <validForProtection>true</validForProtection>
          </protectableVolume>
          <protectableVolume>
            <isExchangeInstallVolume>false</isExchangeInstallVolume>
            <isSqlInstallVolume>false</isSqlInstallVolume>
            <metrics>
              <bytesTransfered>0</bytesTransfered>
              <lastWriteTime>2011-10-13T10:48:48.3833771-04:00</lastWriteTime>
              <totalBytesToTransfer>0</totalBytesToTransfer>
              <transferFinishTime>2011-10-13T10:48:48.3833771-04:00</transferFinishTime>
              <transferStartTime>2011-10-13T10:48:48.3833771-04:00</transferStartTime>
              <volumeName/>
            </metrics>
            <name i:nil="true"/>
            <sqlInstances/>
            <storageGroups/>
            <tevoDriverGuid>301fbef5-de11-11e0-8b0f-76c786fecbc5</tevoDriverGuid>
            <tevoDriverGuidStr>301fbef5-de11-11e0-8b0f-76c786fecbc5</tevoDriverGuidStr>
            <uniqueId>E:</uniqueId>
            <validForProtection>true</validForProtection>
          </protectableVolume>
          <protectableVolume>
            <isExchangeInstallVolume>false</isExchangeInstallVolume>
            <isSqlInstallVolume>false</isSqlInstallVolume>
            <metrics>
              <bytesTransfered>0</bytesTransfered>
              <lastWriteTime>2011-10-13T10:48:48.3833771-04:00</lastWriteTime>
              <totalBytesToTransfer>0</totalBytesToTransfer>
              <transferFinishTime>2011-10-13T10:48:48.3833771-04:00</transferFinishTime>
              <transferStartTime>2011-10-13T10:48:48.3833771-04:00</transferStartTime>
              <volumeName/>
            </metrics>
            <name i:nil="true"/>
            <sqlInstances/>
            <storageGroups/>
            <tevoDriverGuid>b690c188-e454-11e0-a2db-76c786fecbc5</tevoDriverGuid>
            <tevoDriverGuidStr>b690c188-e454-11e0-a2db-76c786fecbc5</tevoDriverGuidStr>
            <uniqueId>F:</uniqueId>
            <validForProtection>true</validForProtection>
          </protectableVolume>
        </protectableVolumes>
        <protectionGroups>
          <protectionGroup>
            <metrics>
              <protectableVolumeMetrics/>
              <transferStatus>Unknown</transferStatus>
            </metrics>
            <name>VolsWithInterval10080Minutes</name>
            <policyFlagsEdb>None</policyFlagsEdb>
            <policyFlagsSql>None</policyFlagsSql>
            <protectionInterval>P7D</protectionInterval>
            <volumes>
              <protectableVolumeContractLite>
                <uniqueId>C:</uniqueId>
              </protectableVolumeContractLite>
            </volumes>
          </protectionGroup>
        </protectionGroups>
        <reachable>true</reachable>
        <remountSqlFlag>true</remountSqlFlag>
        <remountStorageGroupsFlag>true</remountStorageGroupsFlag>
        <replicatedLogPath/>
        <role>Protected</role>
        <rollbackInProgress>false</rollbackInProgress>
        <rollupInProgress>false</rollupInProgress>
        <rpExportSettings>
          <enableExports>false</enableExports>
          <exportStartDateTime>0001-01-01T00:00:00</exportStartDateTime>
          <lastExportedRpTimeStamp>0001-01-01T00:00:00</lastExportedRpTimeStamp>
          <lastPollDateTime>0001-01-01T00:00:00</lastPollDateTime>
          <secondsTillNextPoll>PT0S</secondsTillNextPoll>
          <suspended>false</suspended>
          <timeBetweenUpdates>PT0S</timeBetweenUpdates>
        </rpExportSettings>
        <snapStartDateTime>0001-01-01T00:00:00</snapStartDateTime>
        <sourceLicenseInfo>
          <appMirrorDisplayName>High Availability</appMirrorDisplayName>
          <base64License>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</base64License>
          <companyName>LabTech</companyName>
          <compressionDisplayName>Compression</compressionDisplayName>
          <deduplicationDisplayName>Deduplication</deduplicationDisplayName>
          <dpmEditionDisplayName>DPM Edition (Only use for MailRetriever for DPM)</dpmEditionDisplayName>
          <exchangePackDisplayName>Replay for Exchange</exchangePackDisplayName>
          <expired>false</expired>
          <expiresInMilliseconds>4147753105</expiresInMilliseconds>
          <exportToFolderDisplayName>Rescue Image</exportToFolderDisplayName>
          <hyperVDisplayName>Replay for HyperV host</hyperVDisplayName>
          <invalidMsg/>
          <isAppMirror>true</isAppMirror>
          <isCompression>true</isCompression>
          <isDeduplication>true</isDeduplication>
          <isDpmEdition>false</isDpmEdition>
          <isExchangePack>true</isExchangePack>
          <isExportToFolder>true</isExportToFolder>
          <isHyperV>true</isHyperV>
          <isLiveReplay>true</isLiveReplay>
          <isOffsiteBackup>true</isOffsiteBackup>
          <isReplayMirror>true</isReplayMirror>
          <isRraEnabled>true</isRraEnabled>
          <isSQLPack>true</isSQLPack>
          <isSnapshotDailyEnabled>false</isSnapshotDailyEnabled>
          <isSnapshotHourly>false</isSnapshotHourly>
          <isTrial>false</isTrial>
          <licenseExpireDateTime>2012-08-04T23:59:59-04:00</licenseExpireDateTime>
          <licenseStartDateTime>2011-08-04T00:00:00-04:00</licenseStartDateTime>
          <licenseValid>true</licenseValid>
          <licenseeEmail>dmccallum@labtech.com</licenseeEmail>
          <licenseeName>Drew McCallum</licenseeName>
          <liveReplayDisplayName>Live Replay</liveReplayDisplayName>
          <numDataStoresLicensed>0</numDataStoresLicensed>
          <numMailboxesLicensed>0</numMailboxesLicensed>
          <offsiteBackupDisplayName>Replay Server Option - allows distributed cores</offsiteBackupDisplayName>
          <options xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
            <a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
              <a:Key>option-compression</a:Key>
              <a:Value/>
            </a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
            <a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
              <a:Key>option-deduplication</a:Key>
              <a:Value/>
            </a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
            <a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
              <a:Key>option-exchange</a:Key>
              <a:Value/>
            </a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
            <a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
              <a:Key>option-exportToFolder</a:Key>
              <a:Value/>
            </a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
            <a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
              <a:Key>option-hyperV</a:Key>
              <a:Value/>
            </a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
            <a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
              <a:Key>option-liveReplay</a:Key>
              <a:Value/>
            </a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
            <a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
              <a:Key>option-offsiteBackup</a:Key>
              <a:Value/>
            </a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
            <a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
              <a:Key>option-physicalStandby</a:Key>
              <a:Value/>
            </a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
            <a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
              <a:Key>option-recoverAnywhere</a:Key>
              <a:Value/>
            </a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
            <a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
              <a:Key>option-replayMirror</a:Key>
              <a:Value/>
            </a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
            <a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
              <a:Key>option-sql</a:Key>
              <a:Value/>
            </a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
          </options>
          <optionsDisplayNames xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
            <a:string>Compression</a:string>
            <a:string>Deduplication</a:string>
            <a:string>Replay for Exchange</a:string>
            <a:string>Rescue Image</a:string>
            <a:string>Replay for HyperV host</a:string>
            <a:string>Live Replay</a:string>
            <a:string>Replay Server Option - allows distributed cores</a:string>
            <a:string>High Availability</a:string>
            <a:string>Restore to Dissimilar Hardware Option</a:string>
            <a:string>Off-Site Replication Option</a:string>
            <a:string>Replay for SQL</a:string>
          </optionsDisplayNames>
          <orderDateTime>2011-08-04T16:46:13.5985502-04:00</orderDateTime>
          <orderNumber/>
          <products>
            <product>
              <displayName>Replay for Windows Server</displayName>
              <id>product-agent</id>
              <majorVersion>4</majorVersion>
              <minorVersion>5</minorVersion>
            </product>
            <product>
              <displayName>MailRetriever</displayName>
              <id>product-dsm</id>
              <majorVersion>4</majorVersion>
              <minorVersion>5</minorVersion>
            </product>
          </products>
          <replayMirrorDisplayName>Off-Site Replication Option</replayMirrorDisplayName>
          <rraEnabledDisplayName>Restore to Dissimilar Hardware Option</rraEnabledDisplayName>
          <snapshotDailyDisplayName>Daily Snapshots Only</snapshotDailyDisplayName>
          <snapshotHourlyDisplayName>Hourly Snapshots Only</snapshotHourlyDisplayName>
          <sqlPackDisplayName>Replay for SQL</sqlPackDisplayName>
          <thisProduct>
            <displayName>Replay for Windows Server</displayName>
            <id>product-agent</id>
            <majorVersion>4</majorVersion>
            <minorVersion>5</minorVersion>
          </thisProduct>
          <timeRemaining>-P296DT13H11M10.6322617S</timeRemaining>
          <trialDisplayName>Make Key a Trial</trialDisplayName>
        </sourceLicenseInfo>
        <sourceRollupPolicy>
          <daysToKeepAllSnaps>1</daysToKeepAllSnaps>
          <daysToKeepDailySnaps>7</daysToKeepDailySnaps>
          <daysToKeepHourlySnaps>2</daysToKeepHourlySnaps>
          <monthsToKeepMonthlySnaps>12</monthsToKeepMonthlySnaps>
          <schedule>
            <recurrence>Nightly</recurrence>
            <weeklyDayOfWeek>Sunday</weeklyDayOfWeek>
          </schedule>
          <weeksToKeepWeeklySnaps>5</weeksToKeepWeeklySnaps>
        </sourceRollupPolicy>
        <sqlInstances/>
        <sqlVersion>None</sqlVersion>
        <statusInfoAvailable>true</statusInfoAvailable>
        <storageGroups/>
        <totalPhysicalRamBytes>1069142016</totalPhysicalRamBytes>
        <version>4.6.1.34188</version>
        <volsAndStatuses/>
        <wallClockDateTime>2011-10-13T10:48:44.6144263-04:00</wallClockDateTime>
      </agentStatus>
    </agentStatusList>
  </response>
</responses>
```

Comment: try adding a namespacemanager to the calls. The overloads of those functions can take a NamespaceManager object, and you'll need this to work with the namespaces you defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your nodes are all in a non-blank namespace, and you have not specified this namespace in your XPath query. That's why it finds nothing.

Example:

```
Dim resolver = New XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable)
resolver.AddNamespace("c", "replayc.Xml.Contracts")
Dim node = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//c:response/c:agentStatusList/c:agentStatus/c:protectableVolumes/c:protectableVolume/c:metrics/c:lastWriteTime", resolver)
```

The namespace prefix you use in the XPath text is completely arbitrary, as long as the URI it is mapped to matches the namespace URI in the document.

Comment: +1 you were a bit faster. :) I've lost track on how often this very issue comes up here...

Answer (score 0):

Your XML document has a default namespace (`xmlns="replayc.Xml.Contracts"`).

You must register that namespace prior to issuing XPath queries and of course you must use the namespace in the query itself.

```
Dim nsMgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc)
nsMgr.AddNamespace("c", "replayc.Xml.Contracts")

Dim xpath As String = "//c:response/c:agentStatusList/c:agentStatus/c:protectableVolumes/c:protectableVolume/c:metrics/c:lastWriteTime"
Dim node As XmlNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(xpath, nsMgr)

MsgBox(node.FirstChild.Value)
```

Comment: `Dim nsMgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc)` throws a type conversion error.